# js each loop add one more depth to an object or array

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have this array of pages urls, now i need to make a hierarchy of out it.

So from this:

```
   allPages = [
       { "url": "/polygon/color/red.html", "name": "Red" }, 
       { "url": "/polygon/color/blue.html", "name": "Blue" }, 
       { "url": "/polygon/shape/tri.html", "name": "Triangle" }, 
       { "url": "/weight/heavy.html", "name": "Heavy Item" }
   ];
```

To this:

```
siteMap = [
    polygon:
        color:
            [{url:"red.html", name:"Red"}],
            [{url:"blue.html", name:"Blue"}],
        shape:
            [{url:"tri.html", name:"Triangle"}],
    weight: 
        [{url:"heavy.html", name:"Heavy Item"}],
];
```

The final structure can be object or array. But i can only use JS, not jQuery nor php.

EDIT: Changed Input data into array of objects. Sorry for making this harder.

Comment: this sounds like an assignment of some kind can you start to attempt the code that would be necessary. A good first step would be some way of identifying a `/`

Comment: @BillPull lol, this is not an assignment, even if it is, does this matter to this question? it is actually harder than it looks.

Comment: Just usually on stack overflow you get better answers if you attempt to solve it first. That way people can help you when you are stuck rather than just doing the work for you for a very specific question

Comment: @BillPull i have been working on this for 2 days now. attempted over 20 methods now. there is no way i can keep track of all of them. and i dont see the point of putting my last not working attempted as i believe its not even close to the right path :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ss92kw4a/2/

several steps:

First we split the strings into arrays:

```
for(i in all){
    all[i] = all[i].substring(1).split("/");     
}
```

Next we do a recursive insertion:

```
function insert(o, a){
    if(a.length == 0){return; }
    if(!o[a[0]]){
        o[a[0]] = {};
    }
    insert(o[a[0]], a.slice(1));
}
```

We start the recursion like this:

```
ans = {};

all.forEach(function(entry){
    insert(ans, entry);
});
```

All done. The result tree is now in the ans object:

```
console.log(ans);
```

[image]

UPDATE: this code makes the last level an array: https://jsfiddle.net/ss92kw4a/3/

Comment: Is it possible to do similar process when the items in the array are objects? Eg. allPages = [{
    "url": "/polygon/color/red.html",
    "name": "Red"
}, {
    "url": "/polygon/color/blue.html",
    "name": "Blue"
}, {
    "url": "/polygon/shape/tri.html",
    "name": "Triangle"
}, {
    "url": "/weight/heavy.html",
    "name": "Heavy Item"
}];

Answer (score 0):

You may use something like this:

```
var allPages = [
    "/polygon/color/red.html",
    "/polygon/color/green.html",
    "/polygon/color/blue.html",
    "/polygon/shape/tri.html",
    "/polygon/shape/rect.html",
    "/weight/heavy.html",
    "/weight/light.html"
];
var siteMap = {};
for (var i in allPages) {
    var fragments = allPages[i].match(/[^\/]+/g);
    if (!!fragments) {
        var currentMember = siteMap;
        for (var j in fragments) {
            fragment = fragments[j];
            if(!currentMember.hasOwnProperty(fragment)) {
                currentMember[fragment] = {};
            }
            currentMember = currentMember[fragment];
        }
    }
}
```

Might be enhanced, notably in the fact that ending leaves are objects, 
but it works.